# Test class trigger.NewMap trigger.oldMap on opportunity

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, opportunity, after-trigger, trigger-oldmap

I need to write a test class on my OpportunityTriggerHandler and I'm having some difficulties to define how to construct the logic & scenarios in my test to test and the data to build in my test setup using @TestSetup to provide to my test

here my Test class : OpportunityTriggerHandlerTest that I'm having trouble with :

```java
@isTest
public with sharing class OpportunityTriggerHandlerTest {
    public OpportunityTriggerHandlerTest() {
    }
    
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData(){
        // data to provide to my test 
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void testClosedWon(){
        Test.startTest();
        // call data with : Map<Id,Opportunity> retrieveDataInsertedinTestSetupOpportunityMap= [SELECT ];
    
        //INSERT LOGIC 
        //all or none
        //Database.SaveResult dbResult = Database.insert(retrieveDataInsertedinTestSetupOpportunityMap, false);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(!dbResult.isSuccess);
        System.assertEquals('error',dbResult.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    
    }   
}
```

If you can help me, I need to construct the logic and the data to provide to my test to cover the code, I'm not familiar at all with test class and pretty new to it

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One of the key mantras in unit testing is

*Code for unit tests is very similar to writing "regular" code*

If you've written code to create an SObject (any SObject, pick your favorite) outside of a unit test, then you're 95% of the way to doing it in the context of a unit test. The other 5% is knowing what other records you need to create to be able to insert that test record.

The biggest pain that you'll need to work through here is inserting at least one `OpportunityLineItem` record (OLI for short). OLI requires a `PricebookEntry` record (which requires a `Product2` record, and optionally a `Pricebook` record), and an `Opportunity` record.

I think that `Opportunity` requires an `Account` as well (though that may just be my org), but even if it isn't strictly necessary, the code you're trying to test *does* make use of it so you should make one anyway.

Your setup method here should end up looking something like this

```
Account testAccount = new Account(
    // set required fields as name=value pairs
);

insert testAccount;

Product2 testProduct = new Product2(
   // set required fields as name=value pairs
);

insert testProduct;

PricebookEntry testPBE = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
    Product2Id = testProduct.Id,
    Price = 1.00
);

insert testPBE;

Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(
    AccountId = testAccount.Id,
    Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
    // other required fields
);

insert testOpp;

OpportunityLineItem testOLI = new OpportunityLineItem(
    OpportunityId = testOpp.Id,
    PricebookEntryId = testPBE.Id,
    UnitPrice = testPBE.Price,
    Quantity = 1
);

insert testOLI;
```

Nothing too hard there, just a bit tedious.

It's worth considering making a helper class for your tests (a test data factory) to make it so that you're filling in required fields in one central location as opposed to *in every individual test class*. If you (or someone else) marks a new field as "required", or adds a new validation rule, etc... it's a lot easier to make a change to one class than it is to hunt down all of your test classes.

That's worth considering, but not strictly required. For now, I'd just keep that idea in the back of your mind and try to focus on unit testing.

#### Data created in a `@testSetup` method needs to be queried in individual tests

Static variables are cleared out between test methods, and between running `@testSetup` method(s) and your test method proper. So inside your `@isTest` method(s), you'll need to query for the test data you inserted in your `@testSetup` method.

Yeah, it's a bit tedious, but it is supposed to make tests run faster.

#### Considerations to make when testing a handler in a trigger framework

A big part of why trigger frameworks are good is that it allows you to call the code that is run by a trigger *without needing DML*.

This isn't applicable in your situation, but if you don't need data on child or parent records, then using a framework means that you wouldn't need to insert any records at all (you could just create the records in-memory, and give them fake Ids if required).

It is important to note that while you don't *need* to perform DML to execute the code you want to test (if you're using a trigger framework), you do still need to cover at least 1 line in your trigger. Good practice here would be to have two test methods to gain coverage for your trigger (one for the insert path, one for the update path).

#### Tests really shouldn't have that much "logic" in them

Ideally, test methods are short, simple, and stress a single situation.

Most of the tests I write look something like this

```java
@isTest
static void testAParticularSituation(){
    // Fetch the data to use for the test
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE {conditions here}]);
    Map<Id, Opportunity> newMap = oldMap.clone();

    // This is about as much "logic" as should be present in a test.
    // Here, we're setting up a difference between the old and new record.
    // We're setting up the test data to be in a particular state so that
    //   we can predict (and/or dictate) which path the code being tested will take
    for(Opportunity opp :newMap.values()){
        opp.StageName = 'Closed - Won';
    }

    // Query the 'before' state of SObjects we know will be affected
    Map<Id, Account> accountsBefore = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);

    // startTest() gives you a fresh set of limits
    // it should generally be used _right before_ you call the code to be tested
    Test.startTest();
    OppHandler.someMethod(oldMap, newMap);
    Test.stopTest();

    // Gather results
    // Query the 'after' state of SObjects we know will be affected
    Map<Id, Account> accountsAfter = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);

    // Make assertions
    // Things like "we should have one more account after running the code",
    //   or "the test opportunities should have field X changed"
    // Using the optional "message" parameter in your assertions (with a meaningful message)
    //   can make debugging a lot easier
    System.assertEquals(1, accountsAfter.size() - accountsBefore.size(), 'Should have created one new account');

    // Querying the before and after state makes it easy to do things like
    //   correlate the 'before' and 'after' records to one another and make
    //   assertions based on newly created (or deleted) records
    for(Account acct :accountsAfter.values()){
        if(accountsBefore.containsKey(acct.Id){
            // inside here, the account existed before running the test
        }else{
            // inside here, we know that this is a new account inserted as
            //   a result of running the test
        }
    }
}
```

In general, there are 3 steps to a test:

1. Prepare the test data
2. Execute the code you want to test
3. Gather the results, and make assertions to verify that your code behaved the way you think it should

#### You should generally have more than one test method

Keeping each individual test method focused on testing a single scenario helps keep individual tests simple.

Having many individual tests to stress a variety of situations gets you code coverage. Testing a variety of situations also helps give you confidence that your code is *robust* (i.e. it can tolerate bad input rather than crashing and burning).

As for what scenarios to test, that's a sense you gain over time. Some general examples of things to test are:

- Write a test to make sure you enter a specific `if` block

  - ...and also a test to make sure you enter the `else`
- Write a test where your main record has child records
- Write a test where your main record *does not* have child records
- If you have code that executes when a particular field has a particular value, write a test where that field has a different value

  - as well as a test where that field is null

"Positive" tests are those where the input is well-formed and exactly what you expect. It's also important to write *"negative"* tests (where input is bad/malformed/otherwise unexpected).

Comment: one point where i may need some hints and enlightments is about the test data factory class you just exposed, do i need a test data factory in case I hava already a test setup. I may have missed that point

Comment: @Fatih A test data factory isn't required. The main purpose of such a thing is to help reduce repeated code (i.e. the DRY principle, Don't Repeat Yourself) and to make it easy to fix tests when your admin breaks things by adding a new validation rule.